# Correct way to save foreign key using ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I already tried to save foreign key using ModelForm,but I got this error:

```
The LabRequestForm could not be created because the data didn't validate.
```

Here is my code:

model.py

```
class LabRequestForm(models.Model):
    # lab request form 
    product_name = models.ForeignKey(ProductName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    batch_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    sampling_time = models.DateTimeField()
    lab_test_number = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
```

forms.py

```
class LabRequestModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LabRequestForm
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def sampler(request):
    detect_user = Account.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    if detect_user.is_sampler:
        if request.method == "POST":
            prod_name = ProductName.objects.get(product_name=request.POST.get('product_name'))
            lab_req_form = LabRequestModelForm(request.POST)
            lab_req_form_obj = lab_req_form.save(commit=False)
            lab_req_form_obj.product_name = prod_name
            if lab_req_form_obj.is_valid():
                lab_req_form_obj.save()
                messages.info(request, 'Form Saved')
            else:
                print('not valid')
                messages.error(request, "Form is not valid")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Manually I checked every POST data, they were correct. So I suspect `lab_req_form.save(commit=False)` is the main culprit.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling save before validation is happend. Your `save(commit=False)` should be under `if lab_req_form.is_valid()`. Also you are calling `is_valid` on object, not on form. This should work

```
@login_required
def sampler(request):
    detect_user = Account.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    if detect_user.is_sampler:
        if request.method == "POST":
            prod_name = ProductName.objects.get(product_name=request.POST.get('product_name'))
            lab_req_form = LabRequestModelForm(request.POST)
            # should validate lab_req_form not lab_req_form_obj
            if lab_req_form.is_valid():
                # moved here
                lab_req_form_obj = lab_req_form.save(commit=False)
                lab_req_form_obj.product_name = prod_name
                lab_req_form_obj.save()
                messages.info(request, 'Form Saved')
            else:
                print('not valid')
                messages.error(request, "Form is not valid")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: Applying your suggestion, I get an invalid form. It says my form is not valid

Comment: @pyprism this means your form didn't validate. This is whole another problem and isn't related to your questino